# Effect of Generators and Relations on a Finite Group's Order

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, relations, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Say we define a group $G$ by generators and relations and have shown that $G$ is finite. If we then create a group $G'$ by imposing one additional relation on $G$ which is not implied by any of the original ones, then is it always true that the order of $G'$ is strictly less than $G$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes.

Formally, let $G=\langle X\mid R\rangle$ be a presentation for $G$; let $r\in F(X)$ be an element of the free group in $X$ such that $r$ is not an element of $\langle R\rangle^{F(X)}$; that is, a word that is not implied by the relations $R$. Let $S=R\cup\{r\}$. And let $G’=\langle X\mid S\rangle$.

Since $R\subseteq S$, the identity map $X\to X$ induces a map from $G$ onto $G’$, by von Dyck’s Theorem. This corresponds to the fact that if $N=\langle R\rangle^{F(X)}$ and $M=\langle S\rangle^{F(X)}$, then $G\cong F(X)/N$ and $G’\cong F(X)/M$, and $N\leq M$ so we have a natural map $G\to G’$. However, $r\in M\setminus N$, so the image of $r$ in $G$ is nontrivial and maps to the identity in $G’$. Thus, the kernel of the morphism $\varphi\colon G\to G’$ is nontrivial.

Since you are assuming that $G$ is finite, the nontriviality of the kernel implies that $|G’|$ is strictly less than $|G|$.

Comment: I'm wondering where the mistake may lie in the less rigorous proof I gave to OP when the question was asked earlier: Consider a collection of $n$ generators and relations amongst the generators generating a group $G.$ Now $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup $H$ of $F,$ the free group on $n$ generators. Adding a relation induces a subset $H′ \subseteq H.$ We cannot have $H′=H$ since this would imply the extra relation was redundant. Thus, the new group $G′$ is isomorphic to $H′ \subsetneq H \cong G,$ which implies $|G′|<|G|.$ Note that we had to use the fact that all the groups involved are finite.

Comment: @Displayname: What do you mean “$G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $F$”? If $G$ is given by generators and relations, then it is a **quotient** of $F$, not a subgroup. And the extra relation would give you a **larger** subgroup. But you don’t just look at the subgroup generated by the relations: you have to look at the *normal closure* of the subgroup generated by the relations. And subgroups of free groups are either trivial or infinite, so you would not be able to conclude different cardinality from proper inclusion, nor do you every use finiteness in your sketch.

Comment: Alright. I suppose quotienting by the relations as you did with $M, N$ would be the way to go then. I don't know enough about subquotients to fix my attempted proof.

Comment: @Displayname: As written, your argument makes no sense; it's not fixable. You are trying to identify arbitrary groups with subgroups of a free group, but every subgroup of a free group is free. And I don't use "subquotients": it's just plain quotients. I don't know what you were trying to do, but you seem to think that a group given by generators and relations describes a subgroup of a free group, when it describes a **quotient**.